# Ensure 'flash' messages in controller and view files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and I would like to know if I use this in my controller

```
flash[:notice] = "The <b>#{@user.name}</b> was successfully created.".html_safe
```

and then output that `flash` message in a view file is sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup that is what you do.

`app/views/index.html.erb`

```
<%= flash[:notice] %>
<%= flash[:message] %>
```

Or whatever the name of your flash is.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand your answer at all. Is it sure or not to use the code posted in the question? Rails "handles" data security?

Comment: I ask this because when I (using a related form for the '@user.name' inputting) POST a record  like, for example, '<i>User name test</i>' (this, in the example, corresponds to the '@user.name' data) I get the "italic typography version" on outputting data with the 'flash[:notice]'. So I think that a malicious person can add some unsafe JavaScript (or some other of unsafe) code.

Comment: There is a method `strip_tags` that will remedy that problem.